# Spring user transaction with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions

I want to control hibernate transaction myself so I can rollback at any time. I calling a thread to do business but not waiting for it to finish its job and update DB. This update is only available when the method ends but I want to commit changes in each for loop so I need to control hibernate transaction.

My Sample code is below:

```
for(BaseFileprocess fileProcess : unprocessedFiles) {
            BaseFileprocessfunctype functionType = fileProcessFunctionTypeService.findBySerno(fileProcess.getFunctioncodeserno());
            if(functionType != null) {
                taskExecutor.execute(new ServiceCallThread(functionType.getFunctionname(), fileProcess.getSerno(), fileProcess.getFilename()));
                fileProcess.setStatu("1");
                fileProcessService.update(fileProcess);//I need commit here
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("There is no defined Function Type");
            }
        }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: That bit of code isn't really interesting, we need to see the bit that does the hibernate work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into Spring's [transactionTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html#tx-prog-template). From the docs:

```
// single TransactionTemplate shared amongst all methods in this instance
private final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

// use constructor-injection to supply the PlatformTransactionManager
public SimpleService(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    Assert.notNull(transactionManager, "The 'transactionManager' argument must not be null.");
    this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
}

public Object someServiceMethod() {
    return transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {

        // the code in this method executes in a transactional context
        public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
            updateOperation1();
            return resultOfUpdateOperation2();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Transaction Template is suitable for me.